# Show javascript results in R Markdown knitr ouput

Tags: javascript, r, r-markdown, knitr

How to show javascript results in R Markdown knitr outputs?

I tried to use the `results` option

````
```{js results = TRUE}
1 + 2 + 3
```
````

but still no results displayed

I expect there is

```
## 6
```

(works like python) not just the code chunk.
Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2):

Install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/). Make sure you can run `node` in your terminal. Then, in your `.Rmd` document:

Write:

````
```{node}
console.log(1 + 2 + 3)
```
````

You'll get:

```
6
```

as expected.

See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html for more detail.